# reference request: theorem regarding immesion of manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

Would anybody come up with a reference for the following theorem in differential geometry?

> Let $N$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $n$ and $Z$ a smooth manifold of dimension $r$. Suppose $f:N\to Z$ is a smooth map such that $f$ has constant rank $k$ on $N$. Let $q\in f(N)$. Then $M=\{p\in N:f(p)=q\}$ is an immersed submanifold of $N$ with dimension $n-k$.

Comment: Search the index for "Constant Rank Theorem" in Lee's *Smooth Manifolds* book.

Comment: @SteveD: Thank you for your quick answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Steve D's comment, this is the **Constant-Rank Level Set Theorem** (Theorem 5.12) in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.